# Display two ModelForm class in a single Django html page

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to create 2 forms and display it in a single Django HTML page. I created 2 Modelform class like this

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"

class ToyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Toy
        fields = "__all__"
```

In the HTML page I am only able to embed the `model = Company`. How can I embed the `Model = Toy` in the same page, what I tried brings up the same Company Form. Here is the html code

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2> Company Form </h2>

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2> Toy Form </h2>

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from myapp.form import CompanyForm, ToyForm
      
def index(request):  
    cform = CompanyForm()
    tform = ToyForm()
    context={'cform':cform, 'tform':tform}
    return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

In **HTML Page**

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2> Company Form </h2>

{{ cform.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2> Toy Form </h2>

{{ tform.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```